# Why C++ template accepting array is not more specialized than one accepting pointer (bis)?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, partial-ordering

<sub>In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48405963/why-c-template-accepting-array-is-not-more-specialized-than-one-accepting-poin), which has indeed the same title but for which I found an answer in the standard. I have continued to dig the subject and finaly find out an example code for which this answer does not apply.</sub>

Let's consider this piece of code:

```
template<class T> void func(T* buf);           //template I
template<size_t N> void func(char (&buf) [N]); //template II

void g(char (&buf)[3])
   {
   func(buf) //Error: ambiguous function call (Clang, GCC, ICC, MSVC)
   }
```

According to the partial ordering rules in [[temp.func.order]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.func.order) and [[temp.deduct.partial]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.partial), *template II* shall be more specialized than *template I* if one interpreted this rules through the execution of this piece of code:

```
template <class T> void func1(T* buf) {}
template <std::size_t N> void func2(char (&buf)[N]) {}

struct invented_T{};
constexpr std::size_t invented_N=42;

void is_template_I_more_specialized(invented_T* buf)
  {
  func2(buf);
  //DO NOT COMPILE
  // => template I is not more specialized than func2
  }

void is_template_II_more_specialized(char (&buf)[invented_N])
  {
  func1(buf);
  //DO COMPILE
  // => template II is more specialized than func1
  }
```

So according to this interpretation, *template II* should be *more specialized*. Why would it not be the case?

Comment: Informal C++ documentation sources (cppreference, msvc documentation etc) say that implicit conversions are not considered when performing deductions for partial ordering. I cannot find any relevant standardese myself. (I have initially posted a comment to this effect under the linked question, then deleted it because it doesn't seem relevant there; but it could be relevant here).

Comment: @n.m. So the call `func1(buf)` would not compile too, so neither of the 2 templates would be more specialized. Is that your idea? That would be an answer I would accept if you posted it.

Comment: These are function templates, and AFAIK there is no such thing as partial specialization of a function template; rather, at the point of the function call, each of the two candidate templates is fully specialized (if possible) on its own terms, producing candidate _overloads_ of the function name, and then the overload resolution rules are applied, as-if there had never been any templates involved at all.  That would reduce the question to "why are `void func(char (&buf)[42])` and `void func(char *buf)` an ambiguous overload pair?" and I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @zwol Your right and then the process of selection the best viable function continues:  the conversion sequence of these two functions calls are equaly ranked, then this following rule is applied [\[over.match.best\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best#1.7): *F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is more specialized than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in [temp.func.order],*

Comment: @Oliv yes exactly this is the idea, but I need to find this in the actual standard text to be absolutely sure,

Comment: @zwol *partial specialization* No one is talking about it. *as-if there had never been any templates involved at all* No, this is most definitely not the case. There is such thing as *function template partial ordering* which is different from overload resolution,

Comment: @zwol with your interpretation it is not possible to choose between `template<class T> void f(T t)` and `template<class T> void f(T* t)` when calling with a pointer argument. The standard prescribes that the second template is used as strictly more specialised.

Comment: @n.m. Ugh, more special rules to memorize.

Comment: @zwol the rule is conceptually very simple. The template that accepts the smallest set of argument types wins. In my example the first template accepts everything and the second one just pointers, so the second one wins. But of course there are exceptions and corner cases.

Comment: @n.m. For function call there is this paragraph [\[temp.deduc.call\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#2) then furthur transformation of reference types are describles in the next paragraph. For partial ordering type deduction, there is only this paragraph [\[temp.deduct.partial\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.partial#5) which is about argument and parameter type transformation, and it only talk about removing the reference. Nothing about array to pointer conversion of the argument as is the case in [temp.deduc.call]. I believe you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As n.m. pointed out in the comment, the reason is that type `T*` cannot be deduced from type `char (&buf)[invented_N]`.

In `is_template_II_more_specialized`, an extra array-to-pointer conversion is applied according to [[temp.deduct.call]/2.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.fct.spec#temp.deduct.call-2.1):

> If P is not a reference type:
>
> - If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion is used in place of A for type deduction; otherwise,
> - ...

This rule only applies for deducing template arguments **from a function call**. For deducing template arguments **during partial ordering**, there is no such conversion applying.

<sub>Conversions that can be applied during partial ordering are described in [temp.deduct.partial]/[5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#5),[6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#6),[7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#7).</sub>

Comment: This is indeed the n.m. conclusion in its comment. Thank you for having written it.

Comment: @Oliv Sorry that I didn't notice the comment... Now I add "as n.m. pointed out" since the comment is earlier than my answer.